# Parsing Peers IP Address in Annouce Response From Tracker Server (bitTorrent)

Tags: bittorrent, tracker

So the following request:

```
torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=%02%21%CA%F9j%A3%CB%94%F0%F5%8DE%8Ex%B0%FC4J%D8%BF&peer_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST&port=6881&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=3353370624&compact=0
```

results in an Announce file being served up. After that file is bendecoded you get:

```
{'peers': '\xb9\x15\xd9\x08\xd8\x05[\xbd_\x15\x1b!', 'interval': 1800, 'complete': 5, 'incomplete': 1}
```

I am pretty much stuck about the

```
'\xb9\x15\xd9\x08\xd8\x05[\xbd_\x15\x1b!'
```

with compact=1 you get:

```
'\xbd_\x15\x1b\n\xb9\x15\xd9\x08\xd8\x05'
```

If this is network order (little endian)?

From [here](http://www.kristenwidman.com/blog/category/hackerschool/) I read:

> Note if you get the peers in the binary model that the last two bytes together encode the port number (i.e. ‘\x1a\xe1′ = 26 * 256 + 225 = 6881).

So maybe '\xd8\x05' make up the port: 216 * 256 + 5 = 55301 or maybe not.

Can someone explain to me how to parse these hex numbers into ip:port addresses?

Been googling this for a while not found much so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [bittorrent specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) and [compact announce extension](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html)

> network order (little endian)?

"Network order" without further qualification [generally is big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking).

> Can someone explain to me how to parse these hex numbers into ip:port addresses?

They're not hex numbers. bencoded data is raw binary without any specific charset. Whatever you're using to display it creates the hex output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Figured it out pretty much going to write up my answer in Python.

Answer (score 3):

So as per the [specification](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification)

> peers: (binary model) Instead of using the dictionary model described above, the peers value may be a string consisting of multiples of 6 bytes. First 4 bytes are the IP address and last 2 bytes are the port number. All in network (big endian) notation.

This is when the compact flag is set to 1 (True) and I am only concerned with this atm as it seems pretty standard.

After parsing the bencoded announce file, pulling out the key 'peers' will give you the multiple of 6 byte string.

This string is binary data and is big endian so to parse the first address we could (in Python):

```
decoded = bdecode(announce) # decode the bencoded announce
binary_ip = decoded['peers']
print len(binary_ip) # this will be a multiple of 6 (ie, 12 = 2 ip:port)
offset = 0
ip1 = struct.unpack_from("!i", binary_ip, offset)[0] # ! = network order(big endian); i = int
first_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("!i", ip1)
offset +=4 # save where the first ip ends and the port begins
port1 = struct.unpack_from("!H", binary_ip, offset)[0] # H = unsigned short
offset += 2
```

Obviously you can loop over this if there are more peer ips to read.